# A proof of the fact that MILP with boolean variables can be expressed as LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, np-complete

Hello i want to propose you this proof that i did in order to prove the fact that when we have a MILP where the integer variables are restricted to 0 and 1 it is possible to write it as LP. Please let me know if something is wrong.
Thanks

Consider a canonical MILP
\begin{equation}\label{milp}
\begin{aligned}
& {\text{min}}
& &  [c_c^T\ c_d^T]^T[x_c\ x_d] \\
& \text{subject to}
& &  Ax \leq b
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $x_c \in \mathbb R^{n_c}$ is a vector representing the continous decision variables and $x_d \in \mathbb B^{n_p}$ represents the integer decision variables. By hypotesis $x_{d_i} \in \{0,1\}$ for any $i=1,...,n_p$. Let us replace each binary variable $x_{d_i} \in \{0,1\}$ with a continuous variable $\tilde x_{d_i} \in [0,1]$. It is clear that
\begin{equation}\label{initeq}
 x_{d_i} \in \{0,1\} \iff \tilde x_{d_i}\tilde x_{d_i}-\tilde x_{d_i}=0\\
\end{equation}
By defining $n_p$ slack decision variables, $\tilde x_{d_i}^e \doteq \tilde x_{d_i}\tilde x_{d_i}$,the problem above can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}\label{milp2}
\begin{aligned}
& {\text{min}}
& &  [c_c^T\ c_d^T]^T[x_c\ \tilde x_d]  \\
& \text{subject to}
& &  Ax \leq b\\
& & & \tilde x_{d_i}^e - \tilde x_{d_i}=0 \hspace{15pt} i=1,...,n_p\\
& & &\tilde x_{d_i}^e=\tilde x_{d_i}\tilde x_{d_i}\\
& & &\tilde x_{d_i} \in [0,1]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Which has nonlinear constraints. By applying what is written here http://www.leandro-coelho.com/linearization-product-variables/ (about the linearisation of a product of binary variables), we obtain:
\begin{equation}\label{milptolp}
\begin{aligned}
& {\text{min}}
& &  [c_c^T\ c_d^T 0]^T[x_c\ \tilde x_d \ x_d^e]  \\
& \text{subject to}
& &  A_ex_{ext} \leq b_e\\
& & & \tilde x_{d_i}^e - \tilde x_{d_i} \leq 0 \hspace{15pt} i=1,...n_p\\
& & & \tilde x_{d_i}^e - \tilde x_{d_i} \geq 0 \\
& & &\tilde x_{d_i}^e \geq 2\tilde x_{d_i}-1 \\
& & &\tilde x_{d_i} \leq 1\\
& & &\tilde x_{d_i} \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which is a Linear Program in the new extended variables $x_{ext}=[x_c\ \tilde x_d \ x_d^e]$.
Which is equivalent to the MILP but expressed as LP, so can be solved in polynomial time (even if the extended variables vector is bigger).

Comment: Having introduced the linearisation, the two problems are not equivalent. There have been proposed numerous such approximations (known as *relaxations*) one of which is the SDP relaxation.

Comment: It's not a linearisation it's an equivalence: By forcing x and y to be solution of the equation $x(1-y)=0$ and given the product of two binary variables $z=xy$ it's equivalent to: $z \leq x, z \leq y, z \geq x+y -1$ when x,y and z $\in [0,1]$  the proof should work. Is there something that i'm missing?

Comment: Linearization of product of binary variables only works when they are, well, binary. You have relaxed the binary condition, hence you cannot use binary product linearization. All you get is an outer approximation.

Comment: BTW, maybe you know already and you simply wanted someone to point out the flaws, but claiming to have derived an exact polynomially sized LP model of a MILP, is the mathematical equivalent of having created a perpetuum mobile.